# plot in python with jitter and size as variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a plot in python with jitter and size as variable. 
I can either do a plot with size as variable (`plt.scatter`) or jitter (`sns.stripplot`)

Sample data (of course my real data is much bigger)

```
import pandas as pd
Test = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': [3, 3, 3, 4], \
                            's' : [1, 4, 9, 20], \
                            't' : ["A", "B","A", "B"]})
```

plot with no jitter but size as variable

```
#Method 1 - no jitter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = Test['x']
s = Test['s']
t = Test['t']

plt.scatter(x = x, y = t, s = s* 100)
```

[image: plot showing overlaping points]

plot with jitter but no size distention

```
#Method 2 - no size
import seaborn as sns
sns.stripplot(x='x', y='t', size  = 10, data= Test, jitter=True)
```

[image: plot with jitter]

Comment: You can add jitter to the scatterplot-with-different-sizes by getting the offsets and add some random noise. See the second part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60165124/12046409)

Comment: @JohanC thank you! it did work. do you how to bring closer "A" and "B", values on axis?

Comment: The y-axis is categorical, so internally 0 and 1. With `plt.ylim(-0.5,1.5)` or `plt.ylim(-0.9,1.9)` A and B should come closer together.

Comment: @JohanC you are a true genius! thank you!